# Can I Use Different Price For Google Product Schema in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, product, price

I have an attribute called google_price. Can this be used in the product schema for Google instead of the price listed in Magento?

I'm looking at my final_price.phtml file and it only uses the "final_price" ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, as google shopping checks the xml against the web page to see if the prices match up. If they don't it will not list the product on google shopping!